# applying the styling of product price to my own text

Tags: magento-1.9

i would like to apply the same styling and CSS of the product price of the magento product view page ( irrespective of which theme is being used) to my own text. How do i do that?
to be clear: if say, the product is worth 100 euro,
i would like the font of and size of that '100' element to be applied to my own text.
i already tried a lot.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path:

```
<your_project>\app\design\frontend\default\<your_theme>\template\catalog\product\price.phtml
```

This template file is for showing price and special prices.

Apply the css for size and font style to the prices shown there.
Also you can changed label of price.
Like if its showing **special price** by default you can change it to "**Special Offer**" etc.

Let me if it works for you.

Comment: however, i dont want to edit core theme files, since i want the change to be theme independent. for example: irrespective of which theme, is being used, I want my text to always take the styling applied of the 'price' like 100 euro. however they apply a lot of css and not just one, so i cant figure out which set of css classes i should do. would it be possible to tellme what i should include inside the class of the 'div' element such that my text inside it always take the style of the price element.

Comment: Yes you can copy that file from base theme and put in your theme than make changes

Comment: Create such extension that overrides price.phtml file. Also add system.xml fille to set configuration for price css and format.

Comment: but, why is overiding necessary, I just want to take the styling applied to the price element, not make changes to existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

It need to be apply by module since it need be theme independent (and you don't wan't to override something in theme).

In module you can have custom css and add it to header by extending class. It will be on every page regardless of theme and don't need to add xml file (nothing to do with theme engine).

Best solution is to use `base theme` because it is main theme for other subthemes. For example: adding there new xml file along with theme will show on all pages regardles of subthemes. If you don't wan't to mess there then do it in module.

From there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373670/how-to-rewrite-head-phtml-in-magento

> If you want to the block file is also untouched, you can rewrite this
>   block file using your own module. In your config.xml file, you should
>   use this

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_head>Namespace_Modulename_Block_Html_Head</html_head>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

> and you should define a block file in
>   app/code/local/Namespace/Moduleame/Block/Html/Head.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head 
{

 protected function _construct()
 {
    $this->setTemplate('app/design/frontend/default/customPackage/template/catalog/html/head.phtml');
 }
}
```

> This way core files are untouched and still you can alter the template
>   path.

Copy template from base. It shouldn't be edited because it is just head block.

Be aware that this time you hardcode template. Best options is to add css by local.xml file in base theme.

Comment: i do not want to override the header with my own code though. I want to apply the styling applied to the 'price' of a product to my own custom text. how do i do that?